plt.subplots() with gridspec in matplotlib
Given that I plot the following:
real = results['real']
pred = results['pred']

# Create the subplots with specified grid ratios
fig_sub, axs_sub = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(8, 6), gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0, 
                                                                   'wspace': 0,
                                                                   'width_ratios': [5, 1],
                                                                   'height_ratios': [1, 5]})
# Turn off axes for specific subplots
axs_sub[0, 0].axis("off")
axs_sub[0, 1].axis("off")
axs_sub[1, 1].axis("off")

# Add the marginal KDE plots
sns.kdeplot(crab_sigma['real'], fill=True, ax=axs_sub[0, 0])
sns.kdeplot(y=crab_sigma['pred'], fill=True, ax=axs_sub[1, 1])

# Add the scatter plot
axs_sub[1, 0].scatter(crab_sigma['real'], crab_sigma['pred'], s=2)
axs_sub[1, 0].axline([0, 0], [1, 1], linestyle='--', color='red')

# Set labels
axs_sub[1, 0].set_xlabel('Real $\log_{10}(\sigma)$', labelpad=10)
axs_sub[1, 0].set_ylabel('Pred. $\log_{10}(\sigma)$', labelpad=10)

# Add ticks on the top and right margins
axs_sub[1, 0].tick_params(top=True, right=True, direction='in')

# Synchronize the axis limits to remove the space
axs_sub[0, 0].set_xlim(axs_sub[1, 0].get_xlim())
axs_sub[1, 1].set_ylim(axs_sub[1, 0].get_ylim())

# Adjust the layout to minimize the space
fig_sub.tight_layout()
plt.show()

result:

How can I plot multiple of these in a plt.subplots()? Say that for example I want to replicate this exact figure in 4 subplots.

Maybe use 4 subfigures, or add your 4 scatter axes with subplots and the kdeplot axes with inset_axes.  If you really want to use GridSpec, nested gridspecs are possible.

This can be done through Figure.subfigures easily, but be aware that this functionality is introduced after matplotlib version 3.4 and it is still provisional.
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
real = tips['tip'].to_numpy()
pred = tips['total_bill'].to_numpy()

# Create the subplots with specified grid ratios
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8), layout="constrained")
sfigs = fig.subfigures(2, 2, hspace=0.05, wspace=0.05)

for sfig in sfigs.ravel():
    axs_sub = sfig.subplots(2, 2, gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0, 'wspace': 0, 'width_ratios': [5, 1], 'height_ratios': [1, 5]})
    # Turn off axes for specific subplots
    axs_sub[0, 0].axis("off")
    axs_sub[0, 1].axis("off")
    axs_sub[1, 1].axis("off")

    # Add the marginal KDE plots
    sns.kdeplot(real, fill=True, ax=axs_sub[0, 0])
    sns.kdeplot(y=pred, fill=True, ax=axs_sub[1, 1])

    # Add the scatter plot
    axs_sub[1, 0].scatter(real, pred, s=2)
    axs_sub[1, 0].axline([0, 0], [1, 1], linestyle='--', color='red')

    # Set labels
    axs_sub[1, 0].set_xlabel(r'Real $\log_{10}(\sigma)$', labelpad=10)
    axs_sub[1, 0].set_ylabel(r'Pred. $\log_{10}(\sigma)$', labelpad=10)

    # Add ticks on the top and right margins
    axs_sub[1, 0].tick_params(top=True, right=True, direction='in')

    # Synchronize the axis limits to remove the space
    axs_sub[0, 0].set_xlim(axs_sub[1, 0].get_xlim())
    axs_sub[1, 1].set_ylim(axs_sub[1, 0].get_ylim())

    # Adjust the layout to minimize the space
fig.show()

The result figure is like as:

